# Issue with services in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, web-services

I m creating a login service to check the user is existing or not in the SQL server management studio??

table:

student

- studid(pk)
- username
- password

I Inserted only one filed

12(studid) abc(username) abc754(password)

I creating service:

```
    public class studentsController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult loginapi(string username, string password)
        {
            using (studangEntities stud = new studangEntities())
            {
                if (username == "" || username == null)
                {
                    var data = new
                    {
                        message = "Enter Email",
                    };
                    return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
                else if (password == "" || password == null)
                {
                    var data = new
                    {
                        message = "Enter Password",
                    };
                    return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
                else
                {
                    var userdata = stud.students.SqlQuery("select * from student where username='" + username + "'and password='" + password + "'").FirstOrDefault();
                    if (userdata != null)
                    {
                        var data = new
                        {
                            message = "Success",
                            data = new { userdata }
                        };
                        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var data = new
                        {
                            message = "Email and password incorrect ",
                        };
                        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
     }
```

Model1.Context.cs

```
namespace ApiDemos
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

    public partial class studangEntities : DbContext
    {
        public studangEntities()
            : base("name=studangEntities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<student> students { get; set; }
    }
}
```

when I check the services:

http://localhost:34307/api/students

```
<student>
<password>abc754</password>
<studid>12</studid>
<username>abc</username>
</student>
</ArrayOfstudent>
```

and when I m check in the postman :

http://localhost:34307/api/students/loginapi?username=xyz&password=xyz123

```
raw

{
"username":"xyz",
"password":"xyz123"
}
body
{
    "studid": 1012,
    "username": "xyz",
    "password": "xyz123"
}

status:201 created
```

my record inserted that is the problem??

What I want to:

I want to the when user enter right credential then

username: abc

password: abc754  then display the success message

and when user enter the wrong credentials

username: xyz

password: xyz123  then display the "Email and password incorrect " but why my record is created????

plz, help.thanks

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `api` here:

```
post http://localhost:34307/api/students/loginapi?username=abc&password=754
```

But as this is a post, it will be better to pass `username` and `password` in the body of your request.

Comment: InPostman url:http://localhost:34307/api/students/loginapi?username=asd&password=asdasdasd when I m passing body ```http://localhost:34307/api/students/loginapi?username=asd&password=asdasdasd```    and then ```{
    "studid": 1011,
    "username": null,
    "password": null
}``` my record inserted that is the problem

Comment: how to check the when user enter wrong credential then print then email and password incorrectly

Answer (score 0):

The login api end point is exposed as HTTP POST and from Postman you're sending the request as HTTP GET. That's why you're getting a 404.

Other issue may be because you didn't declared the HTTP GET with Id.

Comment: I m passing the id  ```student students = db.students.Find(id);``` then give an error parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult Poststudent(Int32, ApiDemos.student)' in 'ApiDemos.Controllers.studentsController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type see this myurl:```http://localhost:34307/api/students/loginapi?username=abc&password=abc754```